# How to redirect to a module in angular2 from the index

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

I'm new to angular2 , I have got a sample login & registration code from online, when i run that it's showing the  index page, but there is a module named "login" inside the app folder.

How to redirect from this index page to login either by code or by typing the url?

right now the project runs on "localhost:3000", this is my Router file:

```js
"use strict";
var router_1 = require('@angular/router');
var index_1 = require('./home/index');
var index_2 = require('./login/index');
var index_3 = require('./register/index');
var index_4 = require('./_guards/index');
var appRoutes = [
{ path: '', component: index_1.HomeComponent, canActivate: [index_4.AuthGuard] },
{ path: 'login', component: index_2.LoginComponent },
{ path: 'register', component: index_3.RegisterComponent },
// otherwise redirect to home
{ path: '**', redirectTo: '' }
];
exports.routing = router_1.RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
//# sourceMappingURL=app.routing.js.map
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to Import the `Router` module

```
import { Router } from "@angular/router";
```

Then inject the `Router` in your `index_1.HomeComponent`'s constructor

```
constructor(private router: Router)
```

In the `ngOnInit` method of your component there might some logic if the user is logged in or not, if not logged in then you can redirect lo the login page like the following way:

```
this.router.navigate(["/login"]);
```

Comment: The only thing i want to do is load the login page, right now it's in the index.php with a "loading..." message and the project url looks like localhost:3000 @Hasan Ibrahim

Comment: "/login/index" this thing i want to load from the index.html in the project folder how ?? @Hasan Ibrahim

Comment: @RanjithM What do you mean by "/login/index" is that another component to load or you just want to use another url for LoginComponent?

Comment: @RanjithM What I understood you want the initial route to be the login page, is it?

Comment: Yes @Hasan Ibrahim

Comment: Then the way I have explained it in my answer is the way of giving the user the feel that the login page is the default page. @RanjithM
Just navigate to the login page from the ngOnInit() method

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to make the LoginComponent the default component in your router-outlet, you can just swap your HomeComponent and LoginComponent. Or you can just redirect your " " to login.
Your route will be like

```
  ...
 { path: '', redirectTo:'login', pathMatch:'full'},
 { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
 { path: 'login',component:LoginComponent},
 ...
```